# Admob : Requesting Consent from European Users

Tags: android, admob, privacy-policy

I want to implement Admob consent request for european users in my Android app, i followed the steps in https://developers.google.com/admob/android/eu-consent ,
but i don't know how to provide a privacy policy URL to put here `privacyUrl = new URL("https://www.your.com/privacyurl");` and what it means exactly or from where can i get it.

any idea will be much apreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have your own website containing a web-page that states your Privacy Policy. You could use `Google Firebase Hosting` to host your website (or even just a single webpage) with your Privacy Policy. Find instructions on how to set-up this at: `https://console.firebase.google.com/project/fir-realtimedatabase-5451e/hosting` You will get a URL that you can use in your code.

Answer (score 3):

it means you need to provide a privacy policy that details what kind of data processing practices you engage in within your app. It also means that you need to disclose your usage of Admob, just as you've read it on the resource linked by you (https://developers.google.com/admob/android/eu-consent).

There's a lot to read about now that the GDPR has been implemented and is in force. I suggest, as the hands-down best [English language resource, the ICO](https://ico.org.uk/for-organisations/guide-to-the-general-data-protection-regulation-gdpr).

(I work on this topic daily, if you want to check out [how it can help you](https://www.iubenda.com/blog/about-googles-eu-user-consent-policy/))